# Python, Tkinter: Calculating days left with tkcalendar

Tags: python, class, object, tkinter

I have two issues.

**One:**

I can't figure out how to calculate days left until a specific date which the user inputs in a calendar interface.

**Secondly:**

I want to use the numbers that the user has input in the interface to do some calculations with, and to watch what is going on I print some of the input to the terminal - however, the `.value` attribute returns "0" and I don't understand why.

Below the `#PROXIMITY` comment in the code you will find the calendar/date. I just want to subtract the date today from the date specified by the user in the calendar interface and output the days left.

Below the `#VALUE` is the calculation that prints "0" when i print the `.value` attribute.

Full code:

```
from tkcalendar import * # Calendar module
import tkinter.messagebox # Import the messagebox module
import datetime
import pickle


task_list = []
task_types = ['Sparetime', 'School', 'Work']

class Task:
    def __init__(self, n, type_, i, m, p, h, v): #(w=8, p, u, n, v):
        self.name = n
        self.type = type_
        self.impact = i
        self.manageability = m
        self.proximity = p
        self.hours = h
        self.value = v
        #self.connectivity = c
        ##self.work = w ##hours of work per day
        ##self.urgency = u
        ##self.note = n
        ##self.value = v



def show_tasks():
    # DELETED: for task in task_list:
    # REPLACED WITH: task = task_list[-1]
    task = task_list[-1]
    #print(
        #'Task:'+task.name + '\n' +
        #'Impact:' + task.impact + '\n' +
        #'Manageability:' + task.manageability + '\n' +
        #'Hours:' + task.hours + '\n'
        #'Value:' + task.value +'\n'
        #)
    print('Task:')
    print(task.name)
    print('\n')
    print('Impact:')
    print(task.impact)
    print('\n')
    print('manageability:')
    print(task.manageability)
    print('\n')
    print('Hours')
    print(task.hours)
    print('\n')
    print('Value:')
    print(task.value)

def open_add_task():
    taskwin = Toplevel(root)
    taskwin.focus_force()
    
    #TITLE
    titlelabel = Label(taskwin, text='Title task concisely:', font=('Roboto',11,'bold')).grid(column=1, row=0)
    name_entry = Entry(taskwin, width=40, justify='center')
    name_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)

    #TYPE
    typelabel = Label(taskwin, text='Type', font=('Roboto',10)).grid(column=0, row=2)
    type_var = StringVar(value=task_types[0])
    OptionMenu(taskwin, type_var, *task_types).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky='nsew')

    #IMPACT
    impactlabel = Label(taskwin, text='Impact', font=('Roboto',10)).grid(column=1, row=2)
    imp_var = StringVar(value=0)
    OptionMenu(taskwin, imp_var, *range(0, 10+1)).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky='ns')

    #MANAGEABILITY
    manlabel = Label(taskwin, text='Manageability', font=('Roboto',10)).grid(column=2, row=2)
    man_var = StringVar(value=0)
    OptionMenu(taskwin, man_var, *range(0, 10+1)).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky='nsew')



    #PROXIMITY
    proximity_label = Label(taskwin, text = 'Choose a deadline', font=('Roboto',10), justify='center')
    proximity_label.grid(column=1, row=4)
    cal = Calendar(taskwin, selectmode='day', year=2021, month=4, day=27)
    cal.grid(column=1, row=5)
    def get_date():
        proximity_output_date.config(text=cal.get_date()) ##the .config didn't work until i did .grid(column=, row=) on seperate lines

    
        



    #HOURS(required)
    hourlabel = Label(taskwin, text='Whole hours \n required', font=('Roboto',10)).grid(column=1, row=16)
    hour_entry = Entry(taskwin, width=4, justify='center')
    hour_entry.grid(column=1, row=17)

    #CONNECTIVITY
    #for index, task in enumerate(task_list):
    #Checkbutton(taskwin, **options).grid(column=0, row=index)
    C_lab = Label(taskwin,text="Check tasks this task is related to").grid(column=1, row=18)
    placement=19
    for task in task_list:
        Checkbutton(taskwin, text=(task.name)).grid(column=1, row=placement, sticky="w")
        placement+=1

    

    #VALUE
    val_var = (int(imp_var.get()))+ (int(man_var.get()))
        
    def add_task():
        if name_entry.get() != '': # If textbox inputfield is NOT empty do this:
            task_list.append(Task(name_entry.get(), type_var.get(), imp_var.get(), man_var.get(), cal.get_date(), hour_entry.get(), val_var))
            show_tasks()
            listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, name_entry.get())
            name_entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
            taskwin.destroy()
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title='Whoops', message='You must enter a task')

        
    next_button = Button(taskwin, text='Next', font=('Roboto',10), command=add_task).grid(column=2, row=placement, sticky="e")
    placement+=1
    
def sort_tasks():
    pass
def delete_task():
    try:
        task_index = listbox_tasks.curselection()[0]
        listbox_tasks.delete(task_index)
    except:
        tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title='Error', message='You must select a task to delete')

def save_tasks():
    pass
    #tasks = listbox_tasks.get(0, listbox_tasks.size())
    #pickle.dump(tasks, open('tasks.dat', 'wb'))
    


    
    
    
    

root = Tk()








task_frame = Frame()
# Create UI
your_tasks_label = Label(root, text='THESE ARE YOUR TASKS:', font=('Roboto',10, 'bold'), justify='center')
your_tasks_label.pack()


scrollbar_tasks = tkinter.Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar_tasks.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)

listbox_tasks = tkinter.Listbox(root, height=10, width=50, font=('Roboto',10), justify='center') # tkinter.Listbox(where it should go, height=x, width=xx)
listbox_tasks.pack()

listbox_tasks.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_tasks.set)
scrollbar_tasks.config(command=listbox_tasks.yview)

try:
    #tasks = pickle.load(open('tasks.dat', 'rb'))
    listbox_tasks.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    for task in task_list:
        listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, task)
except:
    tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title='Phew', message='You have no tasks')

#BUTTONS
Add_Button = Button(root, text='Add New', width=42, command=open_add_task)
Add_Button.pack()

button_delete_task = Button(root, text='Delete task', width=42, command=delete_task)
button_delete_task.pack()


button_save_tasks = Button(root, text='Save tasks', width=42, command=save_tasks)
button_save_tasks.pack()

#sort_type = StringVar(value='All')
#OptionMenu(btn_frame, sort_type, 'All', *task_types).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')

#sort_imp = StringVar(value='Any')
#OptionMenu(btn_frame, sort_imp,'Any', *range(0, 10+1)).grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='nsew')

#Button(btn_frame, text='Sort', command=sort_tasks).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='nsew')
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first issue, you can use `cal.selection_get()` to return the selected date in `datetime.date` type.  Then you can calculate the days left easily:

```py
selected = cal.selection_get()
delta = (selected - datetime.date.today()).days
status = "overdue" if delta <= 0 else f"{delta} days left"
print(f"{selected} ({status})")
```

For second issue, you need to move the line `val_var = (int(imp_var.get()))+ (int(man_var.get()))` into `add_task()` function:

```py
def add_task():
    if name_entry.get() != '':
        val_var = int(imp_var.get()) + int(man_var.get())
        ...
    else:
        ...
```

Note that you need to do some validations on the values returned by `imp_var.get()` and `man_var.get()` to avoid exception due to invalid values.

Comment: Thank you for your help - very sincerely appreciated!
the ```cal.selection_get()``` returns the date specified in this line: ```cal = Calendar(taskwin, selectmode='day', year=2021, month=4, day=27)``` which frustrates me a bit right now.

Also, why did I have to move the ```val_var``` line into the ```def add_task():``` - I don't follow that because there are other things in the same function which are defined outside of the function and they seem to work?

Comment: You get 0 because the line is outside the function and at the time the line is being executed, user has not yet changed the values.  Moving into the function so that it is executed after user has changed the values and click the `Next` button.

Comment: `cal.selection_get()` should be called when you have selected the required day on the calendar and need to calculate the days left.

Comment: But actually - and sorry that I am being an annoying rookie with a shallow understanding of this - but the ```imp_var``` and ```man_var``` is outside of the function still, but when they are being called it still seems to be the values that the user has input. Feel like I am missing something completely here

Comment: Although the two variables are created outside the function, their *current values* should only be retrieved *whenever* you need by calling their `.get()` function.  Inside `add_task()` is the right place to do it, not after they have just been created.  You need to learn about event driven programming.

Answer (score 2):

*how to calculate days left until a specific date*

You might subtract `datetime.date` from `datetime.date` to get `datetime.timedelta` object holding numbers of days, consider following example

```
import datetime
d1 = datetime.date(2021, 1, 1)  # year, month, day
d2 = datetime.date(2021, 1, 10)
diff21 = (d2-d1).days
diff12 = (d1-d2).days
print(diff21)
print(diff12)
```

output

```
9
-9
```

For getting current date you might use `datetime.date.today()`.

Comment: Thank you - I checked that out already though, and the problem (at least i think it is) is that tkcalendar  is the form "*year/month/day*" and datetime is the form"*year-month-day*" and i need tkcalendar, because the user must select a date in the interface.